# How to prove that if the integral of a nonnegative function is zero, then the function is zero

Tags: calculus, general-topology

This is required to prove that the expression $d(f,g)=\int|f-g|dt$ is a metric. We need to show that if $\int |f-g|dt=0$ then $f=g$. It seems obvious but how to prove it? This relation is not given in Paul's Online Math Notes for example.

f,g continuous on [a,b]

Comment: This is not true without assumptions on $f,g$

Comment: Start thinking of $a_k\ge 0$ and $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n=0$. What can you say of $a_k$ and why?

Comment: But we don't have $\Sigma a_i=0$, we only have Lim $\Sigma a_i=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u \ge 0$ is continuous then $$0 \le \int_a^x u(t) \, dt \le \int_a^b u(t) \, dt = 0$$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Write $F(x) = \displaystyle \int_a^x u(t) \, dt.$ It follows that $F$ is identically zero, and by the fundamental theorem of calculus $F'(x) = u(x)$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. Thus $u(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$ and since  $u$ is continuous, $u(a) = u(b) = 0$ too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's forget continuity for a minute.

Let $u$ be a measurable function that's also non-negative almost everywhere on $I=[a, b]$, such that $$\int_a^bu=0$$
Then for $\epsilon>0$,  let $$S_\epsilon=\{x\in[a,b] \textrm{  such that  } u(x)\geq\epsilon\}$$
Then by definition of $S_\epsilon$, $$\int_a^bu\geq\int_{S_\epsilon}u\geq\epsilon\mu(S_\epsilon)$$
where $\mu(S_\epsilon)$ is the Lebesgue measure of $S_\epsilon$.

That inequality $$\int_a^bu\geq\epsilon\mu(S_\epsilon)$$ is known as the Chebyshev inequality.

Because $u$ has a $0$ integral on $[a,b]$, it follows that $S_\epsilon$ is of measure $0$. So $u<\epsilon$ almost everywhere on $[a, b]$, and that, for all $\epsilon >0$. It's now easy to conclude that $u=0$ almost everywhere (for instance take the sequence $\epsilon_n=\frac 1 n$).

Now if you assume that $u$ is also continuous, that means that $u=0$ everywhere on $[a, b]$.

Finally, in the world of probabilities, this is how you prove that if a random variable has zero variance, the that variable is not that random: It is constant, almost surely.

Comment: I followed you up to the point where you said "u as o integral..." Sorry, but I don't know what that means. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The assumption is that the integral of u is 0 on [a,b].  Because of the Chebyshev inequality, since $\epsilon>0$, we must have that $\mu(S_\epsilon)=0$

Comment: I guess "o" is zero. Never heard of that notation. I looked up Chebysheve inequality and it is a theorem about random variables. What is the random variable here? It does no good to answer a question if the answer is so terse that the reader cannot understand it! If I were as advanced as you, i would not have had to ask the question.

Comment: The answer I gave you is self-contained. The inequality in question is spelled out and proven in my response. No need to have knowledge from probabilities. At the end of my answer, I try build a connection with the world of probabilities, as I thought it could be interesting to the reader who's already familiar with probabilities, but you are free to ignore that part. 
I'm sorry that my answer seems too advanced to you. Feel free to ask others for an another answer that you'll like better. Mine is correct.

Comment: Does anyone here feel humble enough to explain the answer to a person who is not familiar with measure theory? The problem was given in a book that assumes only a background in first-year calculus.

Comment: How do you feel about Umberto's answer above? I think it's simpler and better than the one I gave you.

Comment: Looks good, thank you