# Proof that f = g a.e. with Fatou's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In the book "A user friendly introduction to Lebesgue measure and integration" by Nelson, Exercise 24 in Ch. 2 states:

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions in $\mathcal L [a,b]$. Suppose $f \in \mathcal L [a,b]$ and
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b|f_n-f| = 0.
$$
If the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise a.e. on $[a,b]$ to the function $g$, show that $f=g$ a.e. on $[a,b]$.
Suggestion: Consider the sequence $(|f-f_n|)$ and Fatou's Lemma.

My try:

From $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n  =g$ a.e., we know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}  f_n -f  =  g - f$ a.e. and $\lim_{n\to\infty} | f_n -f | = | g - f|$ a.e.. Integrating, we have
\begin{align}
0\leq \int_a^b|g-f|&=\int_a^b\lim_{n\to\infty}|f_n -f|=\int_a^b\liminf_{n\to\infty}|f_n -f|\\
&\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b|f_n -f| = 0,
\end{align}
where the second inequality follows from Fatou's lemma and the last step from the assumption that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_a^b|f_n-f| = 0$. We conclude that $|g-f| = 0$ a.e..

Is this the correct direction to approach the exercise? I don't see how to go from the above result to showing that $f=g$ a.e.. I see that $\int_a^b(g-f) \leq \int_a^b|g-f|$...

Comment: yes it's correct.

Comment: You have shown that $\int_{a}^{b}\left\lvert g-f\right\rvert = 0$, and also have $\left\lvert g-f\right\rvert \geq 0$. Those two facts are sufficient to conclude that $\left\lvert g-f\right\rvert = 0$ a.e.: see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2974157/how-to-prove-that-if-the-integral-of-a-nonnegative-function-is-zero-then-the-fu.

Comment: Thanks. I failed to see that $|g-f|=0$ a.e. directly implies $g=f$ a.e. - thus the confusion.

Comment: Tbh, I am not sure how to conclude this. Don't we have to assume that $f,g \geq 0$ a.e.?

Comment: @Flo The fact that $|g-f|=0$ a.e. means that there exists a measurable set $A$, whose measure is zero, such that for every $x \notin A$, $|g(x)-f(x)|=0$. This means that for every $x \notin A$, $g(x)=f(x)$, so because $\mu(A)=0$, that $f=g$ a.e.